# Regex must have letters only and one dot

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to build a regex that must contain letters only and one dot.

There is a **restriction**: the dot cannot be placed in beginning or the end.

**Example:**

```
abc.difference
```

**I tried to use**

```js
^[a-zA-z]*(\d*\.\d*)[a-zA-z]*$
```

Comment: The `\d` matches a **digit** (0 - 9), not a letter.

Comment: Is the dot optional or mandatory?

Comment: wouldn't it just be `^[a-zA-Z]+\.[a-zA-Z]+$`

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 2):

f the dot can go missing in the input string, you can use

```js
/^[A-Za-z]+(?:\.[A-Za-z]+)?$/
```

If the dot is obligatory:

```js
/^[A-Za-z]+\.[A-Za-z]+$/
```

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `[A-Za-z]+` - one or more letter chars
- `(?:\.[A-Za-z]+)?` - an optional occurrence of

  - `\.` - a dot
  - `[A-Za-z]+` - one or more alpha chars
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Also, FYI, see [regex #1 demo](https://regex101.com/r/dBJowi/3) and [regex #2 demo](https://regex101.com/r/dBJowi/4).